# Trac site usage in intranet

Tags: iis-6, log-files, awstats

I need to track the usage on the intranet. I would like to be able to see how many times every file in the intranet are accessed. I have been looking into using a tool that parses the access logs but it does not seem possible see how many times every page has been visited. Cam you recommend any tool?
We are mostly using windows servers with IIS6

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/). You will also need to install perl for this.